# Using Fiddler 4 to intercept game packets?

Tags: proxy, packet, gaming

I can capture packets sent from my browser, but open games fail to connect through the Fiddler proxy. I know that Fiddler is mainly configured for browser applications, but can I force other applications, such as games, to connect through the Fiddler proxy so that I can view their packets?

Comment: This might be best suited for their help desk. That said, if you only want to inspect traffic, how about using WireShark?

Answer (score 3):

Fiddler is an HTTP proxy, so unless the game uses HTTP to communicate it probably won't do you much good.  Many games use UDP instead of TCP, which Fiddler will not be able to handle. You'd probably be better off using [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) to monitor the traffic.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know Fiddler, but I suppose it listen on a given port. You could redirect the port of your game on your local port and after that Fiddler would redirect it to the server game.

Normaly your would have something like that:

YourGame:4545 --> gameServer:xxxx

Now, redirect the stream of the port like this:

YourGame:4545 --> localPortOfFiddler:3456 --> gamerServer:xxxx

Here is how to do this on Windows: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11525703/port-forwarding-in-windows

Hope it fit your needs :)